# UML Representation in specific cases of C# Application

Tags: c#, uml, relationships

I have some UML representation of Class Relationship (Association, Aggregation and Composition) questions

1. In a C# Windows program we always have the Program Calls with Main(). This Main() calls our form say Form1.

   What is the **relationship** between **Class Program** and **Class Form1**
2. A Class C1 has a method M1 which takes one parameter of type Enum Flag

   What is the **relationship** between **Class C1** and **Enum Flag**
3. Class C1 has a property List collection of C2 objects where C2 is another class

   What is the **relationship** between **Class C1** and **Class C2**
4. Form 1 calls a customer dialog Form 2 to get a value

   What is the **relationship** between **Class Form1** and **Class Form2**
5. Class C1 has a property of type Enum Flag

   What is the **relationship** between **Class C1** and **Enum Flag**

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This is an association `Main`-->`Form1` where you would put the role name (e.g. `theForm1`) on the right side of the association
2. This is a simple dependency `C1` - - >`Flag`
3. Also a simple association with multiplicity on the `C2` side of the association. Use composite aggregation only of you want to connect the lifetime of the aggregated children to their aggregator.
4. This is the same as 1.
5. This is the same as 2.